# Did Hitler use a verse from the Quran in one of his speeches?

Tags: history, islam, adolf-hitler, quran

In this book ( سلسلة قادة الحرب - كتاب أدولف هتلر.. الطبعة الاولى - بيروت - صفحة 38 - ترجمة كمال عبدالله. ), the author claims that Hitler quoted a verse from the Quran. Is there any evidence of this?

Translation of the claim, by Google Translate:

> The German leader Adolf Hitler wanted to deliver a speech to the world on the day his armies rushed to Moscow, filling the place and time, and ordered his advisers to choose the strongest and most beautiful and the most beautiful words begin his speech to the world's great .. Whether it is the books of heaven, or the words of philosophers, an Iraqi writer living in Germany said:
>
> **(The clock approached and the moon split)**
>
> ## It's  a verse from Quran
>
> (Adolf Hitler) in this verse and began by his speech and culminated in his speech. If we hope this verse to find the excellence in the brightness .. And the strength to convince .. And authenticity in clarity

Comment: When and where should this speech have happened?

Comment: @FooBar: According to the translated quote, the speech took place "on the day his armies rushed to Moscow". So if there is a list of his speeches somewhere then this should be pretty easy to prove 'true' or 'likely false'.

Comment: @Giter Well, it's a phrase translated from German to Arabic to English. I'm not saying it's impossible to proof one way or the other, but it might not be that easy to find (google mostly finds Nazi Moon conspiracies or Nazi memorabilia; I did find a more common English translation though: "the Hour is near, and the moon was rent asunder").

Comment: @ tim  my translation from Arabic, to English was by Google traduction

Comment: Perhaps it is a start to pinpoint the original Arabic here: where is it from?

Comment: Can you please link directly to site that has info about the book: Kamal Abdullah: "The War of the Wars Series - Book about Adolf Hitler"

Comment: If a book claims someone said something, but doesn't give a date or reference, then it's pretty certain it didn't happen.

Comment: The new horseshoe: I cannot distinguish between claims made by Muslims with an extreme political view, and people with an extreme anti-Islam view.

Comment: While we are at very short quotes, I'm pretty sure Netanyahu himself used in his speeches plenty of words and even some phrases which also appeared in the book "Mein Kampf". Does it mean anything?

Comment: @DJClayworth Just now I wanted to use a quote that I only remembered and in trying to reference it then found hundreds of times on sites like goodreads, brainyquote etc. 'Naturally' I had to find out eventually that it was falsely attributed. Are there any statistics you happen to know to back up your rule of thumb?

Comment: I'm not sure what day *on the day his armies rushed to Moscow* is suppose to refer to. Is that a speech Hitler was planning to give when his armies actually stormed Moscow (spoiler: they never succeeded) ? In this case he would never have delivered it. Or on the first day of Operation Barbarossa ? Or on the first day of Operation Typhoon ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The original Arabic seems to be from Surah 54,1 Al-Qamar:

> The Hour has come near, and the moon has split [in two].
>   __Translation into English from [Quran.com](https://quran.com/54)

What that sentence alone might mean is of course [up for debate](http://www.islamicstudies.info/tafheem.php?sura=54), but the claim seems to explicitly refer to using the quote as is, albeit and in all likelihood in a German version; not the meaning or interpretation of it. That makes the first part quite mundane, and the second part with the description of attributes about the moon the significant part.

In [German the Koran reads](http://islam.de/13827.php?sura=54):

> Näher ist die Stunde (des Gerichts) gekommen, und gespalten hat sich der Mond.

Or [perhaps](http://www.koran-auf-deutsch.de/54-der-mond-al-qamar):

> 1. Die «Stunde» ist nah, und der Mond ist entzwei gespalten.

That is a sentence *start* that Hitler indeed loved.

Translated into German, that would render as *Die Stunde naht/ ist nahe/ ist gekommen…*

Of course, this is common expression in German. Yet, he had a special preference for it. And it  seems equally insignificant as a special expression in the Koran or the Arabic language. To find older – and for a Catholic more fitting sources, one might consult the bible in [John 12:23](https://biblehub.com/john/12-23.htm) or [Matthew 26:45](https://biblehub.com/isr/matthew/26.htm), and several more hits from the New Testament.

For that and close variations you will find many, many hits in his speeches:

> **Die Stunde** der Auseinandersetzung mit den Novembermännern ist damit **gekommen**. / **Die Stunde** der Niederbrechung dieses Terrors **kommt**. / 
>   Es wird **die Stunde kommen**, da wir auch vor die Gräber der Gefallenen des großen Krieges hintreten und sagen werden können:…

Just to quote a few examples. As a Catholic he was also naturally prone to invoke religious imagery in his speeches, one of the better known examples:

> Denn ich  kann mich  nicht lösen von dem Glauben an mein Volk, kann mich  nicht lossagen von der Überzeugung, daß diese Nation wieder einst auferstehen wird, kann mich  nicht entfernen von der Liebe zu diesem meinem Volk und hege felsenfest die Über­zeugung, daß eben doch  einmal **die Stunde kommt,** in der die Millionen, die uns heute hassen, hinter uns stehen und mit uns dann begrüßen werden das gemeinsam geschaffene, mühsam erkämpfte, bitter erworbene neue deutsche Reich  der Größe und der Ehre und der Kraft und der Herrlichkeit und der Gerechtigkeit. Amen."
>
> __Translation: I cannot renounce the conviction that this nation will one day rise again, I cannot renounce my love for this people of mine and I firmly hold the conviction that **the hour will come** when the millions who hate us today will stand behind us and welcome with us the jointly created, laboriously fought, bitterly acquired new German kingdom of greatness and honour and power and glory and justice. Amen."
>
> (February, 10, 1933)

This is however only the first part of the quote. And the examples I quoted were from way before [Operation Barbarossa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Barbarossa), or whatever we might choose to identify "when his armies rushed to Moscow."

He used that *insignificant part* of the quote indeed on June, 22, 1941, the day of the invasion into of the Soviet-Union ([English version on Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_F%C3%BChrer_to_the_German_People:_22_June_1941)). In fact he opened his speech with it:

> „Deutsches Volk! Nationalsozialisten!
>   Von schweren Sorgen bedrückt, zu monatelangem Schweigen verurteilt, ist **nun die Stunde gekommen**, in der ich  endlich  offen sprechen kann.
>
> __Translation: German people! National Socialists!
>   Distressed by grave worries, condemned to months of silence, **the time (hour)** has come when I can finally speak openly.

And he continues in the same speech with it:

> Damit aber ist nunmehr **die Stunde gekommen**, in der es notwendig wird, diesem Komplott der jüdisch-angelsächsischen Kriegsanstifter und der ebenso jüdischen Machthaber der bolschewistischen Moskauer Zentrale entgegenzutreten.
>
> __Translation: Now, however, **the time has come** to oppose this plot by the Jewish Anglo-Saxon war instigators and the equally Jewish rulers of the Bolshevik Moscow headquarters.

But unlike the quote claims, this speech ends quite differently:

> Die Aufgabe dieser Front ist daher nicht mehr der Schutz einzelner Länder, sondern die Sicherung Europas und damit die Rettung aller.
>   I  habe mich  deshalb heute entschlossen, das Schicksal und die Zukunft des Deutschen Reiches und unseres Volkes wieder in die Hand unserer Soldaten zu legen.
>   Möge uns der Herrgott gerade in diesem Kampfe helfen!
>
> __Translation: The task of this front is therefore no longer to protect individual countries, but to secure Europe and thus save everyone.
>   I have therefore decided today to put the fate and future of the German Reich and our people back into the hands of our soldiers.
>   May the Lord help us in this fight!

Quotes in German from: Max Domarus: "Hitler. Reden und Proklamationen 1932–1942. Kommentiert von einem deutschen Zeitgenossen.", Pamminger und Partner: Leonberg, 1988. (Availabe on [archive.org](https://ia800209.us.archive.org/7/items/HitlerRedenUndProklamationen19321945/Hitler%20Reden%20und%20Proklamationen%201932%20-%201945%20vol%201-4%20%28komplett%29%20cs.pdf)[PDF-link])

Looking through all of these speeches searching for the occurence of "Mond" (moon) we find very few hits at all:

> Ich  bin auch  kein Gymnasiast, der in einen Schulatlas Karten einzeichnet. Südamerika liegt so weit weg wie meinetwegen der Mond. Es sind das dümmste Behauptungen.
>   __Translation: I'm not a high school student who draws maps in a school atlas either. South America is as far away as the moon for me. These are the stupidest claims.

The background information surrounding this claim should raise doubts from the beginning. It just wouldn't make any sense to play with religious imagery from the Koran when soldiers are rushing to Moscow. It is known that [Hitler](https://www.nybooks.com/articles/2015/04/02/hitler-and-muslims/) had a "[soft spot for Islam](https://www.tabletmag.com/jewish-arts-and-culture/books/187128/nazi-romance-with-islam)"  whereas Himmler might have had even considerable more interest for that special book.
But the timing is quite off. So, if it were Himmler using that quote in a public speech when the Wehrmacht was rushing towards Belgrad, we would have seen some semblance of plausibility. After all the [SS did recruit some Muslims](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/13th_Waffen_Mountain_Division_of_the_SS_Handschar_(1st_Croatian)) into their ranks from that region.

Who is the most likely candidate for the claim? The mufti of Jerusalem is said to be "[Hitler's Arab friend](http://www.spiegel.de/spiegel/spiegelgeschichte/d-65469611.html)", but it has to be someone from  Iraq the most likely person seems to be  [Rashid Ali al-Gaylani](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rashid_Ali_al-Gaylani). Unfortunately, neither he nor his entourage where in Berlin to advise for any speeches:

> On 25 August 1941, British and Soviet forces invaded Iran and removed Reza Shah from power. Gaylani then fled to German-occupied Europe.

#### Conclusion

Drawing together his remnant Catholic educational background, the lack of evidence for the quote as claimed, and the non-sensical construction to relate a surah, this surah – or in fact anything from the significant part of it relating to the moon – with events that pertain to the invasion of the Soviet-Union, I conclude that this "quote" is not a misunderstanding, nor a mistranslation. It is an invention.

Comment: @Schmuddi Yes this would be the correct approach as the first part of the sentence is so generic that it quite probably does not stem from the quran. I would think that the bible (which outdates the quran) would also have similar wording at some places, though I only suspect that.

Comment: Additionally to this shoud be said that the phrases "Die Stunde naht" and "Die Stunde wird kommen" are very common in German. It is not specific to Hitler.

Comment: @rexkogitans but you must not forget that the nationalsocialist period was very productive (and miserable) in an linguistic understanding. nonetheless, i checked with the ngram-viewer and it shows that this idiom was not new, but had a little renaissance at that time.

Comment: I'm confused by this phrase: "this is common expression in German, despite his knack for it". My intuitive understanding is that this means "Even though Hitler was good at German, he said things which are common in German". Perhaps a different word than "knack" would help clarify?

Comment: @KamilDrakari Thx. You were completely right. Sentence structure was lost in writing and editing.

Comment: @funky-future it literally means "the time is near" or "the hour is upon us", both of which are very common in English as well. And probably in pretty much every language to indicate a soon to be major event of any kind.

Comment: "Es sind das dümmste Behauptungen." is ungrammatical, *Behauptungen* "allegations, claims" has female grammatical gender and thus needs "die" as article. I suppose that's your transcription.

Comment: @vectory You're right in theory, only that *das* isn't the article for *Behauptungen.*

Comment: @LangLangC I must be missing the context. I see no possible grammatical reading of the sentence as quoted here (and I don't have the source before me).

Comment: Try it with a re-ordering or a re-word: Es sind *dies* (die) dümmste(n) Behauptungen. (The source is the PDF link just above the passage, p1778)

Comment: @vectory Reordering gives: Das sind dümmste Behauptungen. Using "Es sind das" is a question of style, it just means "Das sind". Behauptungen, in this sentence, does not have a definite article, but is used here in indefinite plural.

Comment: @kutschkem I am a native German and question your grasp of German. There's a statistically high chance that neither of you is a native German speaker, so I'm sure I don't know what you consider a question of style. Either "Es sind dümmste ..." or "Das sind dümmste ..." alone would work, in a colloquial register (same as *meinetwegen* "for all I care"), but not both. There is a way to read it, sure, which is that he was having a mild stroke or was out of breath, on account of screaming a lot. I see that it's taken from a newspaper scan, it's not a transcription error, you're fine.

Comment: @vectory Thanks for drawing attention to this. But I ask you to read the source, I just copied it. To change it here would mean to alter a quotation. I believe that to be 'not good'. I also believe that it is just a stylistic quirk that makes it sound so awkward. But that is ultimately tangential. I suggest if that still bothers you *that* much to ask about it with your reasoning on [germanSE](https://german.stackexchange.com). You may be right after all.

Comment: I'm sure enough that I don't need to ask. I'm wpn't waste other's time over a minor blip in history and I'm sorry that I've taken yours, but maybe it's helpful to language learners, so it's up to the admins to delete this subthread, or not. However, I think your defense calls into question the whole analysis. After all, if this idiom appears in the Koran and the Bible, it's a reasonable proposition that it has a shared history. Cp. *the last Stand, letztes Stündlein, Stunde der Wahrheit, Gerichtsstand, call X to the Stand, jüngstes Gericht*. I'm not sure about the moon symbolism, though.

Comment: @vectory I am native german, and while you are correct this is not a normal way of saying it, I am certain this works in more formal, and older, settings. Please don't forget this was almost 90 years ago. Language style has changed in that time. Yet I found a similarly structured citation from Joachim Gauck "Es sind dies bewegte Zeiten" https://www.zitate.eu/author/gauck-joachim/zitate/220224  - this is recent!

Comment: *dies*/*das* kind of a difference. So minor a difference that *dies-das* is an idiom for "this and that, nothing much", the usual contrast being *dieses und jenes*. Interesting. *Es sind das* is still findable, it seems to be a southern thing, far from standard. I *stand* corrected.